# Converting from no version control

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working with a group that has multiple versions of a piece of software.

This software has many deploys - each time our client throws a new "Event," we deploy a new rails app for them with it's own DB and place on our server.

Up until now, we have just kept a "master" of each version, and symlinked each install that used that version of the software to that master version.

This allowed us to make changes to the master, and have the 5 installs deployed from that master update (if it was a globally needed bug fix or hotfix), while also allowing us to occasionally throw in an per-install feature that may have only been needed or desired on one of the Events installs.

**What are some effective ways for managing and maintaining such a system?**

**How do I get all of these old version of the software into a repository with the new versions?**

I was thinking that I could do something like: 
create a new branch called "v1.0"
delete all the files 
move the files from the version of the app I wanted to tag
commit those changes
?? some git command that allows me to convert that branch into a tag on master.

This is pure conjecture, and I'll be testing this plus whatever ideas I get from those more experienced with git.

**Finally, if there are any general tips you have for this type of conversion, please share.**

Comment: What is different from one deployment to the next? Minor features? Huge customization? Only a different DB?

Comment: minor features only, nothing huge. Bug fixes are generally for every install (multiple installs per version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pain of managing multiple diverging trees is quite high in my experience.

Instead, I would strongly consider building the different features that your different deployments have into a single source tree and having a really good configuration/feature-flags system to tailor the install to what you need in each instance.  You could even turn the whole thing into a single application, where instead of having multiple deployments, each deployment becomes an "account" inside of it, aka: a multi tenant app.

Comment: Upvoted for making me go look on multitenancy. This would not fly in my organization though, as it would probably be too much work and change. Just convincing people that version management was a prority has been very difficult.

Comment: I feel for you man, getting those kind of changes implemented in organizations that don't quite "get it" is a really trying process. Keep fighting the good fight!

Answer (score 1):

If you have per-install features that cannot be configurable, make per-install branch and rebase it to master when upgrade is required. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing (read that book from the begining).

To import history: I expect you have each version in it's own directory. Then initialize Git repository in the first directory, then create symlinks from each version directory to this new `first/.git`. Now enter `git add . && git commit -a` in each version directory. After that, you will have all commits created, so remove symlinks and move .git directory to the new (empty) directory and type `git reset --hard` (it will restore contets of that empty directory to your last version).

You will want to modify date and author names while doing `git commit`. See manual for your options (`git commit --help`).